# Убрать полосы прокрутки Console C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Пишу мини-игру на Console C#. Для более красивого отображения хочется убрать полосы прокрутки снизу и сбоку консоли. В свойствах консоли такого момента не нашел. Если есть способы , то подскажите , пожалуйста

Comment: Это полосы прокрутки самой `cmd.exe`, а не некой "Console C#", так что вряд ли их можно убрать в принципе. Ищите какой-нибудь эмулятор терминала.

Comment: @arrowd, C# позволяет этим управлять.

Comment: Я думаю, через P/Invoke можно всё.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да куда ж вас всех??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Следует сделать размеры буфера консоли и окна консоли одинаковыми.

Вероятно, следует использовать [`Console.SetBufferSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.setbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`Console.SetWindowSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.setwindowsize(v=vs.110).aspx).